# Angular JS using controllerAs and this syntax with scope or this variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, this, angularjs-controlleras

There is a problem I have always run into and its resulting into inconsistency with the definition of controller scope variables.

As you might be aware that using **controllerAs** syntax you have to attach all the variables with **this** instance inside the **controller function** as shown below:

```
angular.module('angularJsInternationalizationApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (SampleService) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    this.translatedFromService = '';
    SampleService.getTranslation().then(function(data){
        this.translatedFromService = data;
    });
  });
```

Now the problem is **this.translatefDromService** cannot be updated from the **success** or **error** functions of any service or as a matter of fact any other function because it takes this as an instance of the new function and not the controller.

What can be done in such scenarios.

I have used one solution where your tag this to vm.
**var vm = this** at the beginning of the controller but apart from this is there any solution?

Cheers!

Comment: You cannot call service method using this, you need to call it using <service-name>.<method-name>

Comment: I think `var vm = this;` is a perfect solution in this situation. Why do you want alternative to that? Does this not satisfy any of your scenarios?

Comment: I want to remove usage of var declarations for security improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Use the `vm = this` approach, keeping a link to `this` context of the controller:

```
angular.module('angularJsInternationalizationApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (SampleService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    vm.translatedFromService = '';
    SampleService.getTranslation().then(function(data){
        vm.translatedFromService = data;
    });
  });
```

2) Use the `bind()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on the handler, which will modify the context of the invoked function to controller's `this`:

```
angular.module('angularJsInternationalizationApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (SampleService) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    this.translatedFromService = '';
    SampleService.getTranslation().then(function(data){
        this.translatedFromService = data;
    }.bind(this));
  });
```